Why does operator() copy movable temporaries in Clang?
In the following C++23 program
struct A {
    A() {}
    A(A&&) = default;
    void f(this A) {}
    void operator() (this A) {}
};

int main() {
    A{}.f(); // ok
    A{}();   // Clang error
}

struct A is movable, and its member functions f() and operator() have explicit object parameter (this A).
In Clang compiler surprisingly A{}.f() works fine, but A{}() fails with the error:
<source>:10:5: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'A'
<source>:3:5: note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'A' has a user-declared move constructor

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hbfzMvE9f
Is there some difference between functions f() and operator() from the language standpoint that explains their observable treatment by the compiler?

this A, is this some new feature? If yes, what's it called?

@kiner_shah It's called explicit object parameter. And many things broke due to this.

CWG2813 and Move elision in explicit object member functions

I commented the error line and tried to see what happens here, something weird: https://cppinsights.io/s/f5b6ba77

It works if you change to this A&&. Considering that this A works with GCC, it seems like a bug in Clang.

@kiner_shah - cppinsights doesn't handle C++23 syntax changes very well yet; it considers the parameters as an extra one, not the placeholder for the object parameter.

It's still surprising that you only need this A&& for the operator() but not for f()

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yeah thought so.

The program is well-formed. The expression A{}() is equivalent to(interpreted as) A{}.operator()() as per [over.call]

Confirmed clang bug

This is a confirmed clang bug. The program is well-formed. The expression A{}() is equivalent to(interpreted as) A{}.operator()() which clang accepts. Since A{} is a prvalue(and hence an rvalue), the overloaded call operator A::operator()(this A) is a viable option here for the call A{}.operator()().
From over.call:

A function call operator function is a function named operator() that is a member function with an arbitrary number of parameters. It may have default arguments. For an expression of the form
postfix-expression ( expression-listopt )

where the postfix-expression is of class type, the operator function is selected by overload resolution ([over.call.object]).
If a surrogate call function is selected, let e be the result of invoking the corresponding conversion operator function on the postfix-expression;
the expression is interpreted as
e ( expression-listopt )

Otherwise, the expression is interpreted as
postfix-expression . operator () ( expression-listopt ) 



